# Regex Python: Finding nonnumerical subaddress in URL

Tags: python, regex

Maybe my brain is fried but I have looked, searched and tried but can't seem to get this to work.  I've seen and tried posts about using negative look aheads, positive look aheads, not lists [^Characters to not include] and I can't seem to get it to work. I'm trying to get the full sub address domain and all from any URL that isn't all numerical. So I am looking to match:

```
http://www.someaddress.com - www.someaddress.com
http://www.someaddress.com/thiswaytotest - www.someaddress.com/thiswaytotest
http://this.someaddress.test.com - this.someaddress.test.com
http://a.b.c.d.e.f.com - a.b.c.d.e.f.com
a.b.c.d.e.f.com - a.b.c.d.e.f.com
test..test.test.te...test. - test.test.te
(This.website.com.ch) - This.website.com.ch
www.6thday.com - www.6thday.com
7thday.com - 7thday.com
this1time.atbandcamp.org - this1time.atbandcamp.org
http://127.0.0.1 - No match
127.0.0.1 - No match
2000.1 - No match
com. - No match
..com.. - No match
```

I either get numbers included, miss stuff after / , get double periods or my favorite a.b c.d e.f

Please send help.

EDIT:

More details - This is my latest failure ([a-z0-9]+.[^.\s0-9()]+) I'm using 2.7 and I have the ig flags on

Comment: You should include your current implementation so people can help you in the current context you're working with. May also be useful to state python version, 2.7 or 3.x.x?

Comment: I've tried several things.  This is my latest failure ([a-z0-9]+\.[^\.\s0-9\(\)]+)
I'm using 2.7

Comment: oh I should also note I have the ig flags on

Comment: You should add these details to the question.